# Angular/Typescript - Add timestamp in array services

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, service, timestamp

I'm trying to add a timestamp OnInnit in order to record the time a user accessed a page. I would like to add the timestamp in an array found in my services, but I'm really struggling to find my way around this, and keep getting errors. Any help would really be appreciated.

tracker-data.ts

```
export class TrackerData {
  entry?: number;
  exit?: number;
  clicks?: number;
  url?: string;
}
```

tracker.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TrackerData } from '../modules/tracker-data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TrackerService {
  trackerData: TrackerData;
  websiteData: TrackerData[];

  public entryTime: {entry: number} [] = [];

  constructor() { }

}
```

tracker.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { TrackerService } from '../services/tracker.service';
import { TrackerData } from '../modules/tracker-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tracker',
  templateUrl: './tracker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tracker.component.scss']
})
export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

  constructor(
    public trackerService: TrackerService,
    private websiteData: TrackerData[]
    ) { }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    const timeOfEntry = Date.now();
    this.websiteData.push(timeOfEntry); // Type 'number' has no properties in common with type 'TrackerData'.
  }
```

I know the above code might not make sense, but I'm fairly new to this and I'm really trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is pretty clear, you are trying to add a `date` (the timestamp) as an instance of `TrackerData`, which is clearly not. In this case you need to create an instance of the `TrackerData` and then assign the timestamp value.

```
const trackerData = new TrackerData(); // create the instance
trackerData.entry = Date.now(); // assign the the entry timestamp
this.websiteData.push(trackerData); // add to array
```

Answer (score 0):

```
export class TrackerData {
  entry?: number;
  exit?: number;
  clicks?: number = 0;
  url?: string;
}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { TrackerData } from '../modules/tracker-data';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TrackerService {
  websiteData: TrackerData[];
  constructor() { }

  addTrackerData(trackerData: TrackerData): void {
   this.websiteData.push(trackerData);
   //log data on the server if you want
  }
}
```

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { TrackerService } from '../services/tracker.service';
import { TrackerData } from '../modules/tracker-data';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tracker',
  templateUrl: './tracker.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tracker.component.scss']
})
export class TrackerComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  private pageData: TrackerData = new TrackerData();
  constructor(
    private trackerService: TrackerService,
    private router: Router
    ) { }

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target'])
  onClick(btn) {
    this.pageData.clicks++;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.pageData.entry = Date.now();
    this.pageData.url= this.router.url;
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.pageData.exit = Date.now();
    this.trackerService.addTrackerData(this.pageData);
  }
```

this is the simplest version of what you want!
if you want to keep data when the page gets refresh, you need to put data in the cache!

Comment: Please explain _how_ the code works instead of spoon-feeding code to OP.

Comment: What do you want to know? i just answered the exact question! and i put more info for who is curious for more challenging codes! @Edric